# Meteor - how to tell what's causing a template to re-render?

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor template that is rerendering about ~6 times in the first few seconds, making a spinner (spin.js) stutter.

I can't tell why the template itself would be rerendering, and adding `{{#isolate}}` and/or `{{#constant}}` tags isn't helping.

My question: Is there a programmatic way to determine what event or reactive data source is triggering a given rerendering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to figure out which Template Helper is being invalidated, you've got a few options:

1. first is to just edit the source for Meteor `packages/deps/deps.js` and just add a stack trace to the `invalidate` function.

   You can get a stack trace with something like `try{throw new Error('');}catch(ex){ console.log(ex.stack);}`
2. Proxy `Deps.Computation.prototype.invalidate`, similar to (1)

   ```
   var oldInvalidate = Deps.Computation.prototype.invalidate;
   Deps.Computation.prototype.invalidate = function(){
     try{throw new Error('');}catch(ex){ console.log(ex.stack);}
     return oldInvalidate.apply(this,arguments);
   }
   ```
3. Create a reactive function wrapper, which prints a log message when invalidated

   You can do something akin to the `isolate-value` package - but add a logging statement (and remove the value isolation)

   (disclaimer: haven't fully tested this code, but you can get the general idea)

   ```
     logInvalidation = (stmt, fn) ->
       value = null
       outerComputation = Deps.currentComputation
       dep = new Deps.Dependency()
       c = Deps.autorun (c) -> 
         # kill this computation if the computation wrapping the handler is stopped
         if outerComputation?.stopped
           c.stop()
           return
         unless c.firstRun
           # a dependency from `fn` was changed (hence this computation was invalidated)
           # so, invalidate anything that depends on `dep`
           console.log("Helper invalidated #{stmt}")
           dep.changed()
         else
           # attach dependencies in `fn`, and pass result to `value`
           value = fn()
         return
       dep.depend()
       return value
   ```

   And wrap your suspected helpers like so:

   ```
     Template.myTemplate.helpers
       myHelper: ()->
         return logInvalidation 'myHelper invalidated!', ()->
           return Session.get("myValue")
   ```